# Why setting a variable to {} creates dict instead of a set?

Tags: python, set

I have a code like this:

```
a = {}
type(a)
```

> dict

I expect to get:

```
a = {}
type(a)
```

> set

Why is a not being created as a set, how can I create an empty `set`?
Moreover, what is the reason Python was designed this way?

Comment: `a = set()` will create an empty set.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because -- per https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask -- you should only ask **practical**, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**. "Why" questions don't change how you go about the practice of programming, and they aren't based on actual problems. See also [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on a language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `{}` as a `dict` literal predates the `set` type by several years. It simply wasn't available (without breaking backwards compatibility) to use as an empty `set` literal.

(One could argue that Python 3 would have been an opportunity to make `{:}` an empty `dict`, freeing up `{}` for use as an empty `set`. I don't recall if that was every seriously considered, though.)

---

PEP-218, which introduce the `set` type, mentions that `{-}` was considered as a distinct empty `set` literal, but "[e]xperience with Python 2.3's sets.py showed that the notation was not necessary." (Presumably, most people creating set values started with some non-empty, or at least arbitrary, iterable, and didn't not create empty sets specifically.)

Comment: [Apparently](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0218/#set-notation), `{-}` was considered for empty set notation at one point, but deemed unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty set use:

```
a = set()
type(a) 
# set
```